# How to get the final height of a Linearlayout which is populated later with addView()

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a LinearLayout to which i populated other views using addview(); but when i try to get the height of the Linear layout, it returns 0.

I used  `((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearId)).getHeight();`

view i am adding, also has child views. How do i get the height of the Linearlayout including all the children?

EDIT -

actual code i used to adding view to my linear layout -

```
final ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = earningsContainer.getViewTreeObserver();
        viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                // read height with myLinearLayout.getHeight() etc.
                Log.e(TAG, "$$$$$height "+earningsContainer.getHeight());
                // remember to remove the listener if possible
                if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                        viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    } else {
                        viewTreeObserver.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
earningsContainer.addView(getRowTaxEarningsTitle());
        for (int i = 0; i < taxMainObject.getTaxEarnings().size(); i++) {

        earningsContainer.addView(getTaxEarningsRow(taxMainObject
                    .getTaxEarnings().get(i)));
            totalEarnings += taxMainObject.getTaxEarnings().get(i)
                    .getTotalAmount();

        }

        earningsContainer.addView(getTaxTotalRow("GROSS TOTAL SALARY",
                totalEarnings + ""));
```

Stacktrace after using ViewTreeObserver -

```
07-18 13:40:59.936: E/AndroidRuntime(10058): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-18 13:40:59.936: E/AndroidRuntime(10058): Process: com.synthesize.paysal, PID: 10058
07-18 13:40:59.936: E/AndroidRuntime(10058): java.lang.IllegalStateException: This ViewTreeObserver is not alive, call getViewTreeObserver() again
07-18 13:40:59.936: E/AndroidRuntime(10058):    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.checkIsAlive(ViewTreeObserver.java:720)
07-18 13:40:59.936: E/AndroidRuntime(10058):    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(ViewTreeObserver.java:529)
07-18 13:40:59.936: E/AndroidRuntime(10058):    at com.synthesize.paysal.TaxinfoActivity$1.onGlobalLayout(TaxinfoActivity.java:125)
07-18 13:40:59.936: E/AndroidRuntime(10058):    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnGlobalLayout(ViewTreeObserver.java:815)
07-18 13:40:59.936: E/AndroidRuntime(10058):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1782)
07-18 13:40:59.936: E/AndroidRuntime(10058):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
07-18 13:40:59.936: E/AndroidRuntime(10058):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
07-18 13:40:59.936: E/AndroidRuntime(10058):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
07-18 13:40:59.936: E/AndroidRuntime(10058):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
07-18 13:40:59.936: E/AndroidRuntime(10058):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
07-18 13:40:59.936: E/AndroidRuntime(10058):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
07-18 13:40:59.936: E/AndroidRuntime(10058):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-18 13:40:59.936: E/AndroidRuntime(10058):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-18 13:40:59.936: E/AndroidRuntime(10058):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-18 13:40:59.936: E/AndroidRuntime(10058):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-18 13:40:59.936: E/AndroidRuntime(10058):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 13:40:59.936: E/AndroidRuntime(10058):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-18 13:40:59.936: E/AndroidRuntime(10058):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-18 13:40:59.936: E/AndroidRuntime(10058):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-18 13:40:59.936: E/AndroidRuntime(10058):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: try this code in onWindowFocusChanged() method. onWindowsFocusChanged() this is called when all your layouts or UI have been successfully loaded or created properly.

Comment: @David still the same, returns 0 in onWindowFocusChanged(). BTW, i am doing an async call on screen load to fetch the data, which creates the views and adds them to the linearLayout.

Comment: try this after your linear layout gets added myLinearLayout .post(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
         int height = myLinearLayout .getHeight();
    }
});

Comment: @David this too returns 0 for height. :|.

Answer (score 0):

After adding a child to your `LinearLayout` it doesn't perform measure and layout immediately, so at that moment its size is still unknown. You need to wait for for a layout phase to know the dimensions.
You can do it by subclassing your `LinearLayout` and read it's size in onSizeChanged method etc.
OR you can achieve it without subclassing `LinearLayout` by setting a `OnGlobalLayoutListener` on `ViewTreeObserver`:

```
myLinearLayout = ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearId);
```

and then add an `OnGlobalLayoutListener` right before adding your views:

```
myLinearLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        // read height with myLinearLayout.getHeight() etc.

        // remember to remove the listener if possible
        ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = myLinearLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
        if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                viewTreeObserver.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
        }
    }
});
mLinearLayout.addView(view);
```

Comment: @marciej I have place the ViewTreeObserver in the onCreate method, after the declaration of the layout. it is called once, where the height is 0, but then immediately i get this error "`07-18 13:08:47.896: E/AndroidRuntime(9988): java.lang.IllegalStateException: This ViewTreeObserver is not alive, call getViewTreeObserver() again`
" and the app is force closed..... Also, removeGlobalOnLayoutListener() seems to be deprecated, so i used `removeOnGlobalLayoutListener()`, which is for a higher API(16), i am using 11. so added a suppression there.

Comment: I've just tested my code and it works fine for me. Can you please post me your code and entire stacktrace? If you're adding your view not in onCreate, but at other time - you should add this listener only right before adding your child - as I've posted in my snippet.
Yes, `removeGlobalOnLayoutListener` is deprecated, to make it nice you can check for API version and invoke it or `removeOnGlobalOnLayoutListener` if available, this is just a fixe in name (added "On" to be consistend with `addOnGlobalLayoutListener` method)

Comment: okay, i am posting the code and stack trace. meanwhile, Yes, i am adding View to my layout outside onCreate, at three different places, sort of accumulating. should i be adding three different tree observers?

Comment: I cannot see where you adding a `OnGlobalLayoutListener`. You should add it right before adding your childs. BTW. You're adding all these childs in one segment of code? I mean first `getRowTaxEarningsTitle` then `getTaxEarningsRow` in for loop and finally `getTaxTotalRow`? If yes, you can add `OnGlobalLayoutListener` only once before addilng all these children. I've also updated my code to include check if `viewTreeObserver` is alive.

Comment: I have added, the code before adding the layouts(shown in the edits), but still i get 0 as the height. No fatal errors though.

Comment: I've tested such scenario myself at some time before, so it should work fine. This is the solution to achieve your goal, but without any other fragments of your code I'm afraid not able to help you. Maybe you are doing some another things in your code that might affect this behavior. Also I think that the stacktrace is not relevant anymore. In your line when you log the getHeight result please check whether your layout has childs and if it is measured or not (`getMeasuredHeight()`).